# How to customise single row on the basis of sorting in react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to give background color to rows according to column status. But unable to do so. Data is coming from json.

```
<BootstrapTable data={details} options={this.options} search>
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='date'>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='Quantity'>Quantity</TableHeaderColumn
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='Name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
 <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='Status'>Status</TableHeaderColumn>

    </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trClassName` property and change it according the status of the row.

Here is how it will look like:

```
<BootstrapTable
    data={details}
    options={this.options}
    search
    trClassName={this.trClassFormat}
>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='date'>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='quantity'>Quantity</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='status'>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

and the function for example:

```
trClassFormat(row, rowIndex) {
    return row.status === 'In Progress' ? 'red' : 'white'
}
```

Comment: I want to change the color of all rows having a status "In Progress" otherwise it remains white.

Comment: Here is the main check `return row.status === 'In Progress' ? 'red' : 'white'`. Can you please check again the data in `row`? And do you have classes for adding the different colors?

Comment: Nadezhda, I wrote this code only but it is not working."Status" is the header under which all the values of status in json are coming. Now if value of status in json is "In Progress" so it will come under Status header and that row should become blue.

Comment: Can you please change `dataField='Status'` to `dataField='status'`?

Comment: Yes Nadezhda i have changed it but it's not working.

Comment: So please share the code, everything seems to be correct.